# WCF service aync pattern feedback on failed transmission

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, iasyncresult

I am working in Silverlight 4 and implementing a Polling Duplex service with an asynchronous pattern used to update the clients.

```
    // interface for messages back to client
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, AsyncPattern=true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginSendMessage(byte[] MessageData, AsyncCallback callback, object State);

    void EndSendMessage(IAsyncResult result);
```

I make the call back to the client using a RequestState object I defined to keep track of which connected client I sent to.

```
    AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(this.MessageSent);
    RequestState state = new RequestState { ConnectionNo = connectionno};
    client.BeginSendMessage(MessageData, callback, state);
```

I don't see any way to check for an error using the IAsyncResult parameter that is given back in the callback.

So my question is, how can I tell if the message fails to be sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question thanks to the help in this post [Is there a way to get error feedback on asynchronous WCF calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448487/is-there-a-way-to-get-error-feedback-on-asynchronous-wcf-calls) :)

When the callback returns, I find the connection in my connection list again using the ConnectionNo I passed through in the state object.

I then call

```
    try
    {
        //This is the method that is defined in my ServiceContract to complete the AsyncPattern
        client.EndSendMessage(asyncresult);
    }
    catch
    {
        //code here to notify the server that there was an error sending the message
    }
```